# Can not get friends name, pic_quare from Facebook in iOS?

Tags: facebook-graph-api, ios7

When I am Fetching name and pic_square from my friend list the it shows the following error.

```
Error: The operation couldn’t be completed. (com.facebook.sdk error 5.)
FBSDKLog: Error: HTTP status code: 400
FBSDKLog: Response <#1386> <Error>:
The operation couldn’t be completed. (com.facebook.sdk error 5.)
{
"com.facebook.sdk:ErrorSessionKey" = "<FBSession: 0x146f1600, state: FBSessionStateOpen, loginHandler: 0x146cca50, appID: 293072694193895, urlSchemeSuffix: , tokenCachingStrategy:<FBSessionTokenCachingStrategy: 0x1468b170>, expirationDate: 2014-07-17 07:47:12 +0000, refreshDate: 2014-05-18 11:14:42 +0000, attemptedRefreshDate: 0001-12-30 00:00:00 +0000, permissions:(\n    status,\n    permission\n)>";
"com.facebook.sdk:HTTPStatusCode" = 400;
"com.facebook.sdk:ParsedJSONResponseKey" =     (
            {
        body =             {
            error =                 {
                code = 606;
                message = "(#606) The global ID 100003190599973 is not allowed. Please use the application specific ID instead.";
                type = OAuthException;
            };
        };
        code = 400;
    }
);
}
```

here I used the code for retrieving the the required information

```
 NSString *query = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"select name, pic_square from user where uid = %@", curId];
        NSDictionary *queryParam = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:query, @"q", nil];
        // Make the API request that uses FQL
        [FBRequestConnection startWithGraphPath:@"/fql" parameters:queryParam HTTPMethod:@"GET"
                              completionHandler:^(FBRequestConnection *connection, id result, NSError *error)
         {
                                  if (error)
                                      NSLog(@"Error: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
                                  else
                                  {
                                      [namePicArray addObject:result[@"data"]];
                                  }
        }];
```

Thanks in advance.